# Replace number with other number

Tags: python, replace, text-processing

In python, let's suppose that I have the following string:

```
sentence = 'Sum: 100.04 Mean: 23,300 Min:1'
```

I want to have the following:

1)

```
new_sentence_1 = 'Sum: 1.1 Mean: 1,1 Min:1'
```

2)

```
new_sentence_2 = 'Sum: 1 Mean: 1 Min:1'
```

---

At (1) I replace both the integer and the decimal parts of the numbers with 1 (or any integer number - 1 is an example).

At (2) I replace every number as a whole with 1.

---

How can I optimally do each of these replacements?

Comment: `re.sub(r'\d+', '1', sentence)` - simply

Comment: is it expected to be a reusable replacement for multiple cases?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest your question sounds interesting but I am not entirely sure what you mean :) . Could you please elaborate a bit? I do not know if this helps but I want to do these replacements to multiple strings where each string contain multiple numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sentence 1, you could follow @RomanPerekhrest's suggestion in comment section
ie.

```
re.sub(r'\d+', '1', sentence)
```

For sentence 2, you could try this

```
re.sub(r'\d+[.,]?\d*', '1', s)
```

Comment: @PoeteMaudit Glad it works. Feel free to mark as best answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: Sure let me see if any other (better) answers will come up though :)

Comment: Hello @Poete Maudit. Marking as best answer Best answer would certainly keep me motivated to write awesome answers in so

Answer (score 1):

The Swadhikar C is definetely the most clean way of doing for this specific case. If you a different approach where you can work on the numbers on the sentence or join it in other different ways. This is how I would do it:

```
sentence = 'Sum: 100.04 Mean: 23,300 Min:1'
sentence_parts = sentence.split(' ')

sentence_1 = ' '.join([sentence_parts[0], '1.1', sentence_parts[2], '1,1', sentence_parts[-1]])

sentence_2 = ' '.join([sentence_parts[0], '1', sentence_parts[2], '1', sentence_parts[-1]])
```

This way you can work on sentence_parts[1]  and sentence_parts[3], the way you want. Or assemble in different ways by just changing the strings on the join sentence.